# How to solve this Arabic language problem in Sybase PowerBuilder 6 and 7?

Tags: unicode, encoding, fonts, powerbuilder, arabic

How to view arabic characters correctly in Sybase PowerBuilder 6 or 7 as I use Arial(Arabic) or any arabic language in the properties of the table and the database but it shows the characters as strange symbols that has no meaning like ÓíÇÑÉ ÕÛíÑÉ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert in dealing with Arabic language characters, so there may be a work around with ANSI code pages, but I'd expect your best solution is Unicode. There was a distinct version of PB6 supporting Unicode (i.e. a separate product), but it was discontinued in PB6 and there was no Unicode support until it was integrated into the primary product in PB10. However, unless you have the PB6/Unicode product on hand, or you need Win9x support or some other old platform support, I'd recommend moving to something more current, like PB12.5 just out. Not only will you get Unicode, but a lot of features that will help your application look more up to date and integrate better with modern services. (See http://www.techno-kitten.com/Changes_to_PowerBuilder/changes_to_powerbuilder.html for a list that at the moment is a little out of date, but will get the majority of what you're after.)

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: The problem is not yet solved but the link you have sent is useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is called [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) and it's due to the PowerBuilder client and the database using different character encodings. This problem is frequently encountered on the web, and also in email. As Terry suggested, you would get the best results using Unicode in the database and PowerBuilder. If that's not possible, you have to use the same code page on the PowerBuilder client as in the database. A complicating issue is that it sounds like you have existing data. If you want to switch encoding you would have to convert the existing data to the new encoding.